# Windows: Obtaining and Storing a Machine Name in a Variable 

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I have a script that is run over a network, with VPN being the same as a LAN environment.

The script previously worked fine, as we had variables that stored the username and password for the administrator. However, due to a recent change, when we map a drive over the network and whatnot, the machine name is now needed in front of the administator username, E.g. `machinename2343\administrator`.

What I would like to do is take an existing command - perhaps such as nbtstat - and after entering the ip address, have the program pull the machine name and insert it into a variable.

I have found that Nbtstat can give me the machine name, but provides large amounts of unnecessary information for my task. Is there a way to filter out just the machine name in a reliable and consistent manner, or is there perhaps another network related command that perform in the same capacity?

```
`@echo off
```

FOR /f "tokens=1* delims= skip=23 " %%a IN ('nbtstat -a IPADDRESS) DO (
SET VARIABLE=%%a
GOTO Done
)
:Done
echo Computer name: %VARIABLE%`

Comment: you could use findstr. Would you mind getting the Computer name by any other means?

Comment: I'll google findstr right now haha. As far as other means go, I'm unfortunately limited to either vbs (which means the rest of my working code would need to be rewritten) or windows shellcode. I'm open to any other suggestions you may have though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `ping /a`. The computer name is resolved. And this computer name is the second token. I haven't taken care of Error checking. I believe you could implement that yourself.
Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%a IN ('PING -a -n 1 IPADDRESS') DO (
    SET Variable=%%a
    GOTO Done
)
:Done
echo Computer name: %Variable%
```

Put this in your batch file where it would fit.

Comment: When I just use ping -a ipaddress it gives me the regular output of a ping ipaddress. For some reason it does not seem to resolve the machinename. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok actually you pushed me in the right direction. Replacing the ping -a with ('nbtstat -a IPADDRESS') then adjusting the tokens and adding skip=23 I was able to filter it down to nearly what I needed. I'll post the full code once I weed out a couple other bits of erroneous data.

Comment: Excellent Thrustmaster! I had to tweak it a bit but this was spot on. I ended up with the following... <code> @echo off FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=<tab> skip=23 " %%a IN ('nbtstat -a IPADDRESS) DO ( SET VARIABLE=%%a GOTO Done ) :Done echo Computer name: %VARIABLE% Pause <code>

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `%computername%` environment variable.

When I first read your post I thought you were running the batch file remotely on each machine. If that were the case having `%computername%` in the batch file would work, because when the batch file is executed remotely `%computername%` would be expanded based on the remote machine's environment variable not the local machine.

Looking back on it, it's still not very clear, but based on your comment I assume the batch file is running locally and then connecting to a set of machines to perform some operation(s).

You could use tool the WMI command-line tool to get the computer name. The solution would look similar to @Thrustmaster's, but I think it's a little cleaner since the output of wmic, in this case, does "filter out just the machine name in a reliable consistent manner." Of course you'd replace the 127.0.0.1 with the ip you want to query.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('wmic /node:127.0.0.1 ComputerSystem Get Name /Value ^| FIND "="') DO (
    SET COMP.%%A
)
ECHO %COMP.NAME%
```

Comment: The computername env variable is easy to retrieve when on the local machine, I'm trying to pull the machine name over a network having the ipaddress as a means to retreive it, and then store it in a variable. Is there a way to fetch the computername env variable from a remote machine?

Comment: Sorry if the initial question was not clear enough. I had used mapping drives over a VPN as the current example though. Either way, the goal was to retreive a machine name and store it in a variable having the ipaddress to fetch it with. Using Thrusts suggestion and then using nbtstat -a as opposed to ping -a was perfect.                                                                                                                                As this is a corp network we can not install even free MS addons so pstools etc would be out. Thanks for the insight though!